# Connecting Doctrine with Oracle using oci8 not happening

Tags: php, oracle, zend-framework2, oracle-call-interface

I am trying to connect `Doctrine` with `Oracle`. I have installed `oci8` driver & enabled it in `php.ini`.
I have set up the config in `global.php` as

```
   'doctrine' => array(
    'connection' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
 //         'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
            'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOOracle\Driver',
            'params' => array(
                'host'     => '192.168.4.136',
                'port'     => '1521',
                'user'     => 'DRUPAL_SYS',
                'password' => 'drupal_sys123',
                'dbname'   => 'testDB',
                'driver'   => 'oci8',
                'servicename'=>'MYService'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Now, I am trying to generate entities from existing database by the following command. The command is fine as it works with MySQL.

```
  ./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --namespace="Album\\Entity\\" --force  --from-database annotation ./module/Album/src/
```

It throws the following error
[image]

Please help

It seems more to do with ZF2 as it works with simple `php` code.
This sample code works.

```
   <?php
     error_reporting(E_ALL);
     ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
     $conn = oci_connect('DRUPAL_SYS', 'drupal_sys123', '192.168.4.136:1521/MYService');

     $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'select table_name from user_tables');
     oci_execute($stid);
```

Comment: Have you checked the `oci` extension [requirements](http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.requirements.php) and followed the [installation](http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php) instructions?

Comment: it seems more to do with ZF2, i have check writing a `php` program. It works there. added the code in the question.

Comment: Did you also enable the 'php_pdo_oci' driver in 'php.ini'?

Comment: yes, can you tell me what exact steps I need to follow for `ZF2`?

Comment: That error is from PDO, not ZF2. Your code verifies `php_oci` is working but not `php_pdo_oci`. If I run `new PDO('oci:dbname=x', 'y', 'z')` the error I get is the same: `PDOException: could not find driver`. Double check the `php_pdo_oci` extension is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should replace

```
'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOOracle\Driver',
```

with

```
'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\OCI8\Driver',
```